# Configure $(CC) to warn when inclusion is safe to be removed

Tags: c, gcc, include, llvm, compiler-warnings

Read this source code doc:

```
// foo.c
#include<stdint.h>
main(){}
```

I can do this:

```
$ gcc -Wno-implicit-int foo.c
$ ./a.out
$ gcc -dumpversion
6.3.0
```

GCC compiles without warnings.

Let's modify the source:

```
// foo.c
main(){}
```

But the same happens:

```
$ gcc -Wno-implicit-int foo.c
$ ./a.out
$ gcc -dumpversion
6.3.0
```

The output is the same. I want to believe that this means the inclusion can be removed safely.

**Can I configure GCC in order to warn such inclusion can be safely removed?**

**What about the same for LLVM?**

**Is it costly for the compiler to figure out?**

**Would you ever consider activating the feature?**

Comment: I just tried GCC 8.2 using `gcc -Wall` (Linux/Debian/Sid/AMD64) on the second example. Got a warning. Your GCC 6 is becoming old. Upgrade it!

Comment: Compilers tend to issue diagnostics (errors) if there is an error, and give warnings if code is potentially incorrect or ambiguous.   Including an unneeded header is neither - and, in practice,compilers will generally not even attempt to detect whether an "inclusion" can be removed, or provide an option to warn about such a thing.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It's the `-Wno-implicit-int` that suppresses the warning, not necessarily the compiler version. I can synthesize OP's result or yours by using/not using the option on gcc 7.3.1

Comment: @Peter well I guess that qualifies as answer!

Comment: This is not even valid C code. Your `main` lacks a result type, which is not allowed since 19 years (C99). There should be no ned for explicit option..And what do you mean with inclusion"? How is this related to the `#include` proprocessor directive? And why do you disable that warning at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Peter's comment, I'm going address the third question, regarding the cost of this.  TL;DR: this is not functionality that would be trivial to add to a compiler.

Currently, the compiler simply processes the source, line by line, respecting #includes as a means to go and fetch a different source, and insert it at the appropriate place in the input stream.  This is all handled by the preprocessor.

It goes as far as to add some special directives (typically #line), so that error messages match up with where they actually happen, but that's about it.

What would be needed to do what the OP is asking for is for every single declaration to have meta data added to it specifying which file it was found in.  Then as the source is being processed, it would be necessary to mark every declaration that gets used.  Then finally at the end of compilation, the compiler would be have to run over the entire symbol table, to see if any file has the condition that none of the symbols in it were ever used.

That's not a "five line of code" fix, it's going to be a fair sized investment.

And what I've just outlined doesn't begin to deal with nested #includes.  Suppose `outer.c` includes `middle.h`.   Now `middle.h` doesn't have any symbols in it that are used in `outer.c` but it does include `inner.h` that is used.  So without saving the "route" to each variable, you risk throwing away `middle.h` and thus losing `inner.h`.